# размещения с повторениями для букв

Tags: c++, алгоритм, комбинаторика

есть строка "ACGT" как сделать размещения с повторениями, чтобы получилось что-то подобное

```
AAAA
AAAC
AAAG
AAAT
AACA
AACC
AACG
AACT
...
TTTT
```

вообще не могу понять как это делать

Comment: Самый простой вариант - через 4 цикла `for`, вложенные друг в друга.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю как

Comment: `for (int a1 = 0; a1 < 4; a1++) /*аналогично для a2..a4*/ std::cout << "ACGT"[a1] << /*аналогично для a2..a4*/ << '\n';`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем конкретном случае все вообще идеально - по 2 бита на букву, байт на слово - перебираем все 256 слов:

```
const char * d = "ACGT";
for(int i = 0; i <= 255; ++i)
{
    cout << d[i>>6] << d[i>>4&0x03] << d[i>>2&0x03] << d[i&0x03] << endl;
}
```

А в общем случае - просто работаете в системе счисления, где ACGT... - цифры, и все время прибавляете единичку, пока не выведете все числа :)

Comment: не совсем так, там в выводе получается несколько подряд идущих одинаковых значений
TTTC
TTTC
TTTC
TTTC

Comment: Покажите, где: https://ideone.com/yT1D5x - вот работающий код и его вывод.